# Definite Integrals problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The question is to find the value of : $$\frac{\displaystyle29\int_0^1 (1-x^4)^7\,dx}{\displaystyle4\int_0^1 (1-x^4)^6\,dx}$$ without expanding. According to the book, the answer is 7.

I tried taking $I=\displaystyle\int_0^1(1-x⁴)^7\,dx$ and integrating it by parts taking 1 as the function to be integrated, but I could not manage the $-4x^3$ terms that I was getting by the chain rule.

I cannot figure out how to get the answer.

Comment: Maybe you could use some LaTeX here? Otherwise I am afraid your question could be closed even though it may have been a very resourceful question

Comment: I am afraid I do not know how to use latex.

Comment: @Saraswat see here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the integration by parts, you apply a trick. You don't take the constant $1$ as the factor, but you calculate

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (1-x^4)^7\,dx &= \int_0^1 (1-x^4)\cdot(1-x^4)^6\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1 (1-x^4)^6\,dx - \int_0^1 x^4\cdot (1-x^4)^6\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1 (1-x^4)^6\,dx + \frac{1}{28} \int_0^1 x\bigl(7(1-x^4)^6\cdot (-4x^3)\bigr)\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1 (1-x^4)^6\,dx + \frac{1}{28}\biggl(\Bigl[x(1-x^4)^7\Bigr]_0^1 - \int_0^1 (1-x^4)^7\,dx\biggr)\\
&= \int_0^1 (1-x^4)^6\,dx - \frac{1}{28}\int_0^1 (1-x^4)^7\,dx.
\end{align}

Moving the last term to the left and dividing by the factor, we obtain

$$\int_0^1 (1-x^4)^7\,dx = \frac{28}{29} \int_0^1 (1-x^4)^6\,dx,$$

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Replace $x$ with $u^{1/4}$ and exploit the identities:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} u^{-3/4}(1-u)^{m-1}\,du = \frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(m+1/4)},\tag{1}$$
$$ \Gamma(z+1) = z\cdot\Gamma(z).\tag{2} $$

Comment: can you explain the identity?

Comment: @Saraswat: look up [Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).